# Is it possible to display difference between 2 revisions with Gitk as one commit?

Tags: gitk

When I am using `gitk rev1..rev2` it shows difference as list of commits between revisions. Is it possible to combine all of commits and to display it as one commit (something like squash) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left click on rev1. Right click on rev2. Select `Diff selected -> this`.